# Unexpected MVEL2 behavior

Tags: java, hashmap, mvel

I need to check if an expression is well written, so I decide to use MVEL2 to do this.
I have an expression like

```
String expression = "(OPVAL == 'OPERATION') && (DAT > '12345')"
```

and an hash map like

```
Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();

{OPVAL = "OPERATION", DATA = "0"}
```

When I process it with MVEL,

```
(Boolean)MVEL.eval(expression, vars);
```

I'm expecting an exception because DAT is not mapped, instead MVEL2 library return only a FALSE condition.

If I use the expression like

```
String expression = (DAT > '15/11/2014') && (OPVAL == 'Operazione')
```

I get the expected exception, and another example where I get the exception is this:

```
String expression = (OPVAL != "Operazione") AND (DAT < "15/11/2014")
```

Could you please give me an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error in all the three cases.

```
unresolvable property or identifier: DAT
```

**Remember** - While evaluating expression, `"(OPVAL == 'OPERATION') && (DAT > '12345')"`, MVEL uses `AST tree` structure to parse any given expression and then evaluate.

Also if `(OPVAL == 'OPERATION')` is false, then it will never evaluate `(DAT > '12345')` since there is a `&&` operator between the two.

Carefully look once again, and play around with your expression, or move `(DAT > '12345')` in front, and then test.

FYI, refer below code

**Case 1**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String expression = "(OPVAL == 'OPERATION') && (DAT > '12345')";
        Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        vars.put("OPVAL", "OPERATION1");
        vars.put("DATA", "0");
        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(expression, vars));
    }
```

**Output**

```
false
```

Since `(OPVAL == 'OPERATION')` evaluates to false.

**Case 2**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String expression = "(OPVAL == 'OPERATION') && (DAT > '12345')";
        Map<String, Object> vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        vars.put("OPVAL", "OPERATION");
        vars.put("DATA", "0");
        System.out.println(MVEL.eval(expression, vars));
    }
```

**output**

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: DAT]
[Near : {... (OPVAL == 'OPERATION') && (DAT > '12345') ....}]
```

Since in this case, `(OPVAL == 'OPERATION')` evaluates to true, so it further traverses to evaluate `(DAT > '12345')`.

hope it solves your confusion.